# Handling relationships in Mongo and Sails?

Tags: mongodb, sails.js

I'm having a bit of a nightmare at the moment trying to figure out relationships in Mongo and Sailsjs.

At the moment, I have 3 models.  User, Photo and Category:

**User**

```
  attributes: {
    username  : { type: 'string', unique: true },
    first     : { type: 'string', required: true },
    last      : { type: 'string', required: true },
    email     : { type: 'email',  unique: true },
    photos    : { collection: 'photo', via: 'user' },
    passports : { collection: 'passport', via: 'user' },
    shareNum  : { type: 'integer'}
  }
```

**Photo**

```
  attributes: {
    caption  : { type  : 'string' }, 
    fid      : { type  : 'string' },
    user     : { model : 'user' }
  }
```

**Category**

```
  attributes: {
    photo       : { model: 'photo' },
    category    : { type: 'string'}
  }
```

As it stands, when a user uploads a Photo, I have linked the User and Photo models together, and my code takes the User ID from the header and it shows up in my **Photo** collection as an *ObjectID* which confirms to me that the 2 are now linked and related.

What I am now trying to do is add a **Category** to my Photo.  The Category field is to be stored as an array, as a Photo can have multiple Categories.

What I want to do here is store the preset Categories in the Category collection as separate documents.  Lets say we call one Dog and one Cat for now.  When a user uploads a photo with the category array containing Dog and Cat, it will store their ObjectID's in the Photos collection.

I've tried to do the following, but all I can get it to do is to store the actual array values, rather than the associate ObjectID

**Photo**

```
  attributes: {
    caption  : { type  : 'string' }, 
    fid      : { type  : 'string' },
    user     : { model : 'user' },
    categories : { model : 'category', type : 'array'}
  }
```

**Category**

```
  attributes: {
    photo       : { model: 'photo' },
    category    : { type: 'string'},
    categories   : { collection: 'photo', via: 'categories' }
  }
```

I am attempting to do this using the following query:

```
    Photo.create({caption :'var', user : '55cdeb6059798a3f424aa0cb', fid : 'rar', category : ['dog','cat']}).exec(function(err,created) {
console.log('test');
});
```

The query works returning undefined and then test. In my database, I have the array, but it stores the string of cat and dog as an array, rather than the ID they link to in the Category collection.

Do I have to do something first to get the ID for dog and cat?

Comment: When you "attempt to do this using the following query" what happens next? Does it work? Does it not work? Do you get an error? Do you get any results you didn't expect?

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned.  The query works returning undefined and then test. 
In my database, I have the array, but it stores the string of cat and dog as an array, rather than the ID they link to in the Category collection

Comment: Does the category collection serve any purpose but mapping ID's to names? When it doesn't, I would consider the solution with a string array superior. MongoDB is not a relational database. Any unnecessary relations between documents should be avoided. This does of course not answer your question, but I would recommend you to consider it.

Comment: My category table will contain a list of predefined categories.  Within my application, I will be allowing users to select these categories, which will then be sent with the photo upload as per my photo query above.

The reason I am doing it like this is if I need to rename a category later on, I only need to do it within the Category collection, rather than on every single photo which used it.

Comment: When you need to rename a category: `db.photos.update({category:"dog"}, {$pull: { category: "dog"}, $push: {category: "dawg"}}, {multi:true});`. Might take a few minutes with a very large collection, but how often will you have to do this anyway?

Comment: So you're saying the correct way to do this would to be to have the Category collection store the categories, and provide this list to the user.  Then they select the categories they want, and they just get put into the Photo collection with no relation to the Category collection at all?
Im coming from an SQL background, so this all seems a strange way of working to me!

Comment: That's what I would suggest. With MongoDB you should always optimize for the most common use-case. Relations are always bad for performance because they can't be resolved on the database.

Comment: Perhaps another question to be asked then, but how would you go about creating an array of ObjectID's?  Every time I try, they get converted into strings