# How to store array of ObjectID's in Mongo with Sails?

Tags: mongodb, sails.js

After my initial question:
[Handling relationships in Mongo and Sails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32118270/handling-relationships-in-mongo-and-sails)

I managed to use this approach, however I now need to resolve this the way I originally thought.  For example, I have my Photo and Category models & collections, but now my category also contains addresses and business details.

In my Photo model I have the following:

```
attributes: {
    caption  : { type  : 'string' }, 
    fid      : { type  : 'string' },
    user     : { model : 'user' },
    categories : { model : 'category', type : 'array'}
  }
```

In my Category model I have the following:

```
  attributes: {
    photo       : { model: 'photo' },
    category    : { type: 'string'},
    address     : { type: 'string'},
    phone       : { type: 'integer'},

    //Foreign Keys
    categories   : { collection: 'photo', via: 'categories', type : 'integer'}
  }
```

Now I can get the categories in the Photo collection to show as an ObjectID if I removed the type array and just send a single ObjectID of a category,  however in my case, a photo can have more than one Category.

If I try sending an array of ObjectID's in my query, they just show up in the database as a String array.  Is there anyway I get store these as an array of ObjectID's instead?

Answer (score 0):

Basically it's `many to many` relationship. You can use Waterline scheme like this:

**Photo Model**

```
attributes: {
  caption  : { type  : 'string' }, 
  fid      : { type  : 'string' },
  user     : { model : 'user' },
  categories : { collection : 'category', via : 'photos'}
}
```

**Category Model**

```
attributes: {
  photos      : { collection: 'photo', via: 'categories' },
  category    : { type: 'string'},
  address     : { type: 'string'},
  phone       : { type: 'integer'},
}
```

Comment: Thanks, however how would I go about using this in a query.  I'm now doing the following, however I still end up with an array of Strings, not ObjectID's:  Photo.create({caption :'var', user : '55cdeb6059798a3f424aa0cb', fid : 'rar', category : ['55d5c47677c896adc7c05bd1','55d5c48377c896adc7c05bd3']}).exec(function(err,created) {console.log('test');} );

Comment: it's because Waterline convention, handle relation in MongoDB using string, not ObjectID. It's still queryable trough Waterline, but if you want to query it from native Mongo, it should be string.

Comment: Interesting.  When I've linked a user to a photo in the past, the userid has always shown in my database (through MongoChef) as an ObjectID

Comment: Sorry my bad, it's true that it save as an ObjectId, not String. But I don't know why in my past project, all of the relation is saved as String. Maybe it's because Mongo and or Mongo Driver version? What Mongo and sails-mongo version did you use?