# Store array of ObjectId's in sailsjs using waterline ORM

Tags: arrays, mongodb, sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

I'm trying to store array of Object Id's of another model.

**Sub Service**

```
    skills: {
        collection: 'subservice',
        via: 'contractors'
    },
```

**Contractor Model**

```
   contractors : { 
       collection: 'contractor', 
       via: 'skills' 
   },
```

and this solution didn't worked...
[How to store array of ObjectID's in Mongo with Sails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32184048/how-to-store-array-of-objectids-in-mongo-with-sails)

Comment: Can you clarify what "it didn't work" means?  What did you try, what was the expected result, and what actually happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this two models you are using `via` so you must specify which model is dominant:

**Sub Service**

```
skills: {
    collection: 'subservice',
    via: 'contractors',
    domiant: true
},
```

**Contractor Model**

```
contractors : { 
   collection: 'contractor', 
   via: 'skills' 
},
```

More info: http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/dominance